# Stored file length changes after ifstream read

Tags: c++

When reading a file using ifstream I'm seeing that a stored length variable changes from a correct value to an incorrect value after a read.

```
std::ifstream input_stream(this->file_path_, std::ifstream::binary);

if (input_stream) {
  input_stream.seekg(0, input_stream.end);
  this->length_ = input_stream.tellg();
  input_stream.seekg(0, input_stream.beg);

  std::cout << this->length_ << std::endl; // correct

  input_stream.read((char *) & this->data_, this->length_);

  std::cout << this->length_ << std::endl; // wrong

  input_stream.close();
}
```

**UPDATE: Added working implementation**

```
std::ifstream input_stream(this->file_path_, std::ifstream::binary);

if (input_stream) {
  input_stream.seekg(0, input_stream.end);
  this->length_ = input_stream.tellg();
  input_stream.seekg(0, input_stream.beg);

  std::shared_ptr<char> buffer((char *)malloc(sizeof(this->length_)), free);

  std::cout << this->length_ << std::endl; // correct

  input_stream.read(buffer.get(), this->length_);

  std::cout << this->length_ << std::endl; // correct

  input_stream.close();
}
```

I was able to get something to work with the above code but it's still not quite what I need. I haven't been able to get it to work with the uint8_t data_ member. I believe this is a separate question.

Comment: Where did you declare data ? Can you show the header ?

Comment: Value of `length` is being clobbered by `read`. It points to something about how `data_` is defined.

Comment: If `length_` is greater than the size of `data_` then `length_` could  be overwritten by the read (depending on memory layout).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an indication of undefined behavior.

You are calling `input_stream.read` with a buffer whose size is less than `this->length`
Make sure that you buffer is large enough to hold `length` characters.

You wrote past the end of the buffer, transforming your object into garbage (one consequence being that `length` is incorrect after this call)